# Display a button vertically with writing-mode: vertical-rl; and make the button width fit content

Tags: html, css

I need to create a button with a close button and text.

The button might be horizontal, vertical and the content length is dynamic.

The content might be in EN, HE, JA, JO, ZH, etc.

To support JA, JO, ZH, etc, this [article](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/vertical-text/) recommends to add a paragraph element with `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`

So eventually I have the HTML (which works great on chrome, but looks really bad on safari especially on safari mobile. the text is cut and out of the wrapper view):

```css
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}


.wrapper.center-right {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
    top: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform-origin: right top;
    
}
.wrapper.center-right .text-button {
      min-width: auto;
      align-items: initial !important;
}
.wrapper.center-right .text-button .text{
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        max-height: 150px;
}

.text-button,
  .close-btn {
    border: solid 2px red;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-button {
    display: grid;
}
.text-button:focus,
  .close-btn:focus  {
      color: blue;
      outline: none;
      border: blue solid 2px;
    }
  
.text-button:focus .button-text {
      color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center-right">
 <button class="text-button">
  <p class="text">my dynamic text making it a bit longer to reproduce the bug 国际化活动 نشاط التدويل 万维网联盟</p>
 </button>
 <button class="close-btn">
 <img class="close-img" src="some-close-icon-path" />
 </button>
 </div>
```

[image: screen shot from safari]

Comment: it support on all browsers as well, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_writing-mode.asp

Comment: pls provide screenshort

Comment: Added a screen shot from safari (also added some text to the button so you would be able to see the bug. part of the text is hidden)

Comment: check it's useragent css from developer tool